# How Spring store cache and key to Redis

Tags: redis, spring-cache

I follow some tutorial on web to setup Spring Cache with redis,

my function look like this:

```java
@Cacheable(value = "post-single", key = "#id", unless = "#result.shares < 500")
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Post getPostByID(@PathVariable String id) throws PostNotFoundException {
    log.info("get post with id {}", id);
    return postService.getPostByID(id);
}
```

As I understand, the value inside `@Cacheable` is the cache name and `key` is the cache key inside that cache name. I also know Redis is an in-memory key/value store. But now I'm confused about how Spring will store `cache name` to Redis because looks like Redis only manages key and value, not cache name.

Looking for anyone who can explain to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Spring uses `cache name` as the key prefix when storing your data. For example, when you call your endpoint with `id=1` you will see in Redis this key

```
post-single::1
```

You can customize the prefix format through `CacheKeyPrefix` class.

Comment: Thanks @Aleh
i also found how to config cache key prefix here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56764225/how-can-i-prefix-cachenames-with-spring-cache-redis-key-prefix